# positioning text value inside submit to the center

Tags: html, css

I just want to center the text inside submit button. I don't know what do I need to do

I've tried everything i know :

```css
.button {
  vertical-align : middle;
  line-height : 40px;
  padding-bottom : 100px;
  text-align : center;
  margin : auto;
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<input style=' width: 110px; height: 26px;' type=submit  class=button value='Go'>
```

even after that much styling on css it stil looks like that

Comment: there should be some other CSS rule applying to your button...

Comment: could you tell me what the others are?

Comment: I don't know, that is other codes not include in your question. The original browser behavior (at least in Google Chrome) will render the text inside the button as vertical+horizontal center by default. So there should be other codes that making your button looks different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `line-height : 40px;` and `padding-bottom : 100px;` from your code and check this

```css
.button {
  width: 110px; 
  height: 50px;
  background:#ccc;
  vertical-align : middle;
  text-align : center;
  margin : auto;
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<input type=submit  class=button value='Go'>
```

Comment: ah thank you. it works now but padding-bottom and line-height is not the issue here since, it works even with them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `padding-bottom` attribute. That's causing the issue.

```css
.button {
vertical-align : middle;
line-height : 40px;
padding-bottom : none;
text-align : center;
margin : auto;
display : block;
}
```

```html
<input style=' width: 110px; height: 40px;' type=submit  class=button value='Go'>
```

Comment: `padding-bottom` still works even with 100px value with your code. the key is `vertical-align` and `text-align` but the strange thing is that it didn't work before, that is the reason I'm asking here

Comment: @Citra45Abadi Nope, It doesn't. I changed the padding to 100px. [Check the jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5gbmn8xm/)